# Why SpringBoot @PathParam and @RequestParam stopped working if the parameter name is not explicitly defined?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is any one else facing any issues with implicitly defined @PathVariable parameters?

Below code used to work properly but not anymore:

```
@GetMapping("/{caseId}/audit")
getCaseAuditRecords(@PathVariable String caseId)
```

I intermittently keep getting this error in some of my applications:

`{ "errorCode": "BAD_REQUEST", "description": "Name for argument of type [java.lang.String] not specified, and parameter name information not found in class file either." }`

It seems the server is unable to resolve the implicit path variable and I had to explicitly define the parameter name:

`getCaseAuditRecords(@PathVariable("caseId") String caseId)`

I have recently upgraded the Spring Boot version (2.1.1 -> 2.7.5) after which this issue has started appearing. Couldn't find anything in the change logs for this change in behaviour. Their is one blog that talks about the same issue but doesn't exactly pinpoints the root cause:
https://salonegupta.wordpress.com/2014/04/01/spring-annotations-and-javac-debug-mode/#more-5

Anyone else facing this issue lately?

Comment: If you not define name then it will match parameter name as path name. So in your case `caseId` but you have variable `id`. So you have to define name as its different from parameter name `String caseId`.

Comment: I tried the same as well and it still doesn't work. This used to work well earlier.

Comment: I’m doubtful it ever worked. There’s no way for Spring to know to bind the variable to a different name.

Comment: Please provide your request mapping for `getCaseAuditRecords`. As @AbhijitSarkar said there is not way spring know that it needs to bind with diffferent name. So if name are different then you must specify as argument in `@PathVariable`

Comment: Double checked. Updated the code and it won't work when I deploy the code on server.
Unless I explicitly define the name, it won't work.

Comment: I vaguely remember one of the newer Java versions introduced a change that enabled Spring to deduce the annotation name from the variable name. What Java version are you on?